# How do I resolve this error in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

```
Error Code : FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.readium:r2-parser:0.1.5.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.folioreader:folioreader:0.3.9
         project :app > org.readium:r2-fetcher:0.1.5
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve org.readium:r2-server:0.1.5.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.folioreader:folioreader:0.3.9
      > Skipped due to earlier error

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 26s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

My gradle.build :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
 repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
           url "http://dl.bintray.com/mobisystech/maven"}
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

& also the one in "app" folder

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
    }
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.suusoft.ebook"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 4
        versionName '1.3'
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false

        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
    dataBinding true

    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.lsjwzh.RecyclerViewPager:lib:v1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.joooonho:selectableroundedimageview:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.devbrackets.android:exomedia:4.1.0'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.folioreader:folioreader:0.3.9'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.2.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I've tried several ways including :

- Reinstall Android Studio and tried another version
- Allow auto detect proxy (but i think I'm not connected to any proxies)
- Invalidate / Restart IDE

Is there something I miss? Or is there some repository which is out of date / wrong version? Or even wrong code? Please help me, any answer would be appreciated ^_^

Comment: This build error seems specific to the readium dependency which you are using in your project, check the implementation guide for the correct library path for project

Comment: I'm sorry, but where can I check the implementation guide? I have search at jetpack & github but I can't find any :v

Comment: You can raise an issue on the corresponding GitHub library for your build error. First check if there exists same open/close issue on GitHub